# Cordova plugin speech recognition fails on getSupportedLanguages()

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins, speech-recognition

I have a Cordova app using the speech recognition plugin:

https://github.com/pbakondy/cordova-plugin-speechrecognition

The plugin works fine except for a few users where the function `getSupportedLanguages()` fails instead of returning the expected array of supported languages

`getSupportedLanguages()` requires two callback, `success` and `fail`. Normally the `success` is invoked returning the aforementioned array

The documentation doesn't provide any clue about what to do in case the function fails nor it provides any fallback strategies